# Как передать переменную из def в другой файл python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здраствуйте, у меня есть два файла, в одном есть функция def, в которой переменная присваивается чему-то. А во втором файле запускается функция из первого файла, и она должна получить присвоенную переменную, как это сделать? Вот пример кода

***1 файл (test.py)***

```
value = 0
def test():
    value = 1
```

***2 файл***

```
for test.py import test, value
test()
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test.py

```
def func():
    value = 1
    return value
```

2 файл

```
from test import func
value = func()
print(value)
```